# JQuery and hidden fields

Tags: jquery, html

I need to create a hidden field on my page, store some value in it and read that value later.
If i create a regular text input and read its value using jquery, i get the correct value. But if i create a hidden input field,populate it with some text and read its value using jquery i get null.

**example:**

Suppose the following input text box contains the value "Foo".

```
<input type="text" id="inputfield"> </input>
```

Now, if i do `$("#inputfield").val()`, i correctly get "Foo"

But, if i change the type to "hidden", and set the value of field, using `$("#inputfield").val("Foo")` then try to read the value using `$("#inputfield").val()`, it returns "".

Can someone please tell me why this happens and any way to fix this ?

Thank You.

Comment: This should work.  Are you sure you're setting the ID of the hidden text to "inputfield"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked as expected:

```
alert( $("input#fooBox").val() ); // alert default value
$("input#fooBox").val("end test"); // change value
alert( $("input#fooBox").val() ); // alert new value

<input type="hidden" id="fooBox" value="hello world" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not reproducible. Provide more code / html / context information / error messages.

Check here for a correctly working example http://jsbin.com/utunu3/ (http://jsbin.com/utunu3/edit for the code)

```
<input type="hidden" id="inputfield"> </input>
alert($("input#inputfield").val());
$("input#inputfield").val("foo");
alert($("input#inputfield").val());
```

alerts first an empty string then foo.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden fields or other type of input fields should behave the same. Maybe you have another error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t write `type="hidden"`, you either make it invisible by assigning the CSS statement `display: none` or hide it using jQuery’s `$(element).hide();` or `.fadeOut()`.  If you were storing something that is never to be seen by the user, global variables do a good job.